# How can I get maximum value of an array vertically?

Tags: php

I have this kind of data structure

```php
$scores = [
  'user_a' => [75, 67, 80, 90, 20, 80],
  'user_b' => [65, 70, 80, 90, 20, 80],
  'user_c' => [56, 70, 75, 80, 50, 70],
  'user_d' => [40, 50, 89, 56, 45, 78],
  'user_e' => [60, 80, 90, 78, 80, 76],
];
```

I want to get the maximum number from `user_a` to `user_e` each one vertically. What I'm expecting is something like this:

```php
$max = [75, 80, 90, 90, 80];
```

I tried this, but the number is taken horizontally by key.

```php
$max = [];
foreach ($scores as $score) {
  array_push($max, max($score));
}

var_dump($max); // [90, 90, 80, 89, 90];
```

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: it is the matching input already, maybe my explanation is a little bit difficult to understand, please focus on first numbers in the left, read it from top to bottom, and repeat each to the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sophisticated solution but still:

```
$scores = [
  'user_a' => [75, 67, 80, 90, 20, 80],
  'user_b' => [65, 70, 80, 90, 20, 80],
  'user_c' => [56, 70, 75, 80, 50, 70],
  'user_d' => [40, 50, 89, 56, 45, 78],
  'user_e' => [60, 80, 90, 78, 80, 76],
];

$max =  array_map(
    'max', 
    array_map(null, ...array_values($scores))
);
print_r($max);
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/cmalS).

Comment: ahh.. what if i want the min instead of max sir? what helper function should i use?? do you have any clue?

Comment: In this case you should use [`'min'`](https://www.php.net/min) function

Comment: like `...array_values(min($scores))` ?

Comment: oh oh, `array_map('min', ...)` ?

Comment: So try it and see.

Comment: okaayy.. nice! just like what I expect :D

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution if you need more control over the mapped values.

```
<?php

$scores = [
  'user_a' => [75, 67, 80, 90, 20, 80],
  'user_b' => [65, 70, 80, 90, 20, 80],
  'user_c' => [56, 70, 75, 80, 50, 70],
  'user_d' => [40, 50, 89, 56, 45, 78],
  'user_e' => [60, 80, 90, 78, 80, 76],
];

// Get vertical score lines
$verticalScores = array_reduce($scores, function($carry, $score) {
    foreach($score as $key => $value) {
        $carry[$key][] = $value;    
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);


// Get max score per vertical line
$maxScores = array_map('max', $verticalScores);


var_dump($maxScores); //75, 80, 90, 90, 80, 80
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way.  Just extract each column and max:

```
$i = 0;
while($col = array_column($scores, $i)) { $max[] = max($col); $i++; }
```

Or other variations:

```
for($i=0; $col=array_column($scores, $i); $i++, $max[]=max($col));
```

You can do multiple things in those loops, just add `$min[] = min($col);` etc...

To extract the columns for later use:

```
$i = 0;
while($col = array_column($scores, $i)) { $vals[] = $col; $i++; }
```

Then use them how you want:

```
foreach($vals as $col) { 
    $min[] = min($col);
    $max[] = max($col);
}
//or
$max = array_map('max', $vals);
```

Or a function to get the columns and perform a function.  Just pass `min`, `max` or whatever accepts an array:

```
function get_cols($array, $func) {
    for($i=0; $col=array_column($array, $i); $i++) {
        $result[] = $func($col);
    }
    return $result;
}

$max = get_cols($scores, 'max');
```