# I can't get my additive weighting algorithm to work properly

Tags: php

I have a data structure that look like this

```json
$data = [
    [
        "name" => "user_a",
        "code" => "c1",
        "description" => "criteria 1",
        "type" => "benefit",
        "weight" => 25,
        "value" => 75
    ],
    [
        "name" => "user_a",
        "code" => "c2",
        "description" => "criteria 2",
        "type" => "benefit",
        "weight" => 20,
        "value" => 67
    ],
    [
        "name" => "user_a",
        "code" => "c3",
        "description" => "criteria 3",
        "type" => "benefit",
        "weight" => 15,
        "value" => 80
    ],
    [
        "name" => "user_a",
        "code" => "c4",
        "description" => "criteria 4",
        "type" => "benefit",
        "weight" => 22,
        "value" => 90
    ],
    [
        "name" => "user_a",
        "code" => "c5",
        "description" => "criteria 5",
        "type" => "benefit",
        "weight" => 8,
        "value" => 20
    ],
    [
        "name" => "user_a",
        "code" => "c6",
        "description" => "criteria 6",
        "type" => "benefit",
        "weight" => 10,
        "value" => 80
    ],
    [
        "name" => "user_b",
        "code" => "c1",
        "description" => "criteria 1",
        "type" => "benefit",
        "weight" => 25,
        "value" => 65
    ],
    [
        "name" => "user_b",
        "code" => "c2",
        "description" => "criteria 2",
        "type" => "benefit",
        "weight" => 20,
        "value" => 70
    ],
    [
        "name" => "user_b",
        "code" => "c3",
        "description" => "criteria 3",
        "type" => "benefit",
        "weight" => 15,
        "value" => 80
    ],
    [
        "name" => "user_b",
        "code" => "c4",
        "description" => "criteria 4",
        "type" => "benefit",
        "weight" => 22,
        "value" => 90
    ],
    [
        "name" => "user_b",
        "code" => "c5",
        "description" => "criteria 5",
        "type" => "benefit",
        "weight" => 8,
        "value" => 20
    ],
    [
        "name" => "user_b",
        "code" => "c6",
        "description" => "criteria 6",
        "type" => "benefit",
        "weight" => 10,
        "value" => 80
    ],
];
```

I'm trying to get the normalized values but it wasn't giving me the expected result with my current algorithm.

```php
// This one is fine
$matrix_x = get_matrix_x($data);

// result: [
//   "user_a": [75, 67, 80, 90, 20, 80],
//   "user_b": [65, 70, 80, 90, 20, 80],
//   "user_c": [56, 70, 75, 80, 50, 70],
// ];


// This one is producing the wrong result (I rounded it just to make it readable, decimals are OK to be shown as is)
$matrix_r = get_matrix_r($data, $matrix_x);

// current result: [
//   "user_a": [0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 1.0, 0.2, 0.8],
//   "user_b": [0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 1.0, 0.2, 0.8],
//   "user_c": [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 0.6, 0.8],
// ];

// expected result: [
//   "user_a": [1.0, 0.9, 1.0, 1.0, 0.4, 1.0],
//   "user_b": [0.8, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.4, 1.0],
//   "user_c": [0.7, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 1.0, 0.8],
// ];
```

I have been stuck with this problem for about 4 days, the problem is in the `min(...)` and `max(...)` function inside the `get_matrix_r` method. It was supposed to take the number from top to bottom for each column instead of taking the highest/lowest number directly from the key given by `$matrix_x` but I don't know how to do that.

I also asked [a question related to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68291145/how-can-i-get-maximum-value-of-an-array-vertically), but when I loop inside the `$reducer` using the given solutions, it produce extra items in the result. Please help!

`functions.php`

```php
/**
 * Generate matrix_x from the given data.
 * 
 * @param  array $data
 * @param  string $key
 * @param  string $valkey
 * @return array
 */
function get_matrix_x(array $data, string $key = 'name', string $valkey = 'value')
{
    $reducer = function ($acc, $item) use ($key, $valkey) {
        $index = $item[$key];

        if (!isset($acc[$index])) {
            $acc[$index] = [];
        }

        $acc[$index][] = (int) $item[$valkey];

        return $acc;
    };

    return array_reduce($data, $reducer, []);
}

/**
 * Generate matrix_r from data and matrix_x as origin.
 * 
 * @param  array $data
 * @param  array $origin
 * @param  string $key
 * @param  string $valkey
 * @param  string $compkey
 * @return array
 */
function get_matrix_r(array $data, array $origin, string $key = 'name', string $valkey = 'value', string $compkey = 'type')
{
    $reducer = function ($acc, $item) use ($key, $valkey, $origin, $compkey) {
        $index = $item[$key];

        if (!isset($acc[$index])) {
            $acc[$index] = [];
        }

        $item[$compkey] === 'cost'
            ? $acc[$index][] = (int) $item[$valkey] / min($origin[$index])
            : $acc[$index][] = (int) $item[$valkey] / max($origin[$index]);

        return $acc;
    };

    return array_reduce($data, $reducer, []);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain what you want to achieve?? why the first value should be `1` and not  `0.8`?

Comment: yes, it should be `1` and not `0.8` because the `max()` function should take the highest value of each column. For example, in the first column of `matrix_x` from top to bottom, there is `75`, `65` and `56`. So the `max` function should take the `75`. Resulting to a calculation of `75 / 75 = 1`. Same goes to the right column until it ends.

Comment: and for `65` it should be `65 / 75` and so on, to be honest, I'm having a difficulties how to explain it but i hope everyone here got the idea

Comment: yes, but you are not considering the column, you are considering the row...

Comment: oh i'm sorry, my mistake.. I'm having problem trying to explain it by words, but I can provide a visual clue if needed, should I go for it??

Comment: no, wait a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first problem, is that in the dataset you are providing there is not `user_c`, but in the output matrix there are references to that, so that's weird.

The second problem, is that in the reducer, you are considering the ROWs, and not the COLUMNs... to consider those, you should do something like this:

```
/**
 * Generate matrix_r from data and matrix_x as origin.
 * 
 * @param  array $data
 * @param  array $origin
 * @param  string $key
 * @param  string $valkey
 * @param  string $compkey
 * @return array
 */
function get_matrix_r(array $data, array $origin, string $key = 'name', string $valkey = 'value', string $compkey = 'type')
{
     $reducer = function ($acc, $item) use ($key, $valkey, $origin, $compkey) {
          $index = $item[$key];
          print_r($item);
          if (!isset($acc[$index])) {
               $acc[$index] = [];
          }
          // consider the nth COLUMN, with $origin[$index] you was considering the ROW
          $col = array_column($origin, count($acc[$index])); 
          $item[$compkey] === 'cost'
               ? $acc[$index][] = (int) $item[$valkey] / min($col)
               : $acc[$index][] = (int) $item[$valkey] / max($col);

          return $acc;
     };

     return array_reduce($data, $reducer, []);
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! I noticed it and just about to update the references but I never thought the solution will be as simple as that. Thank you so much!